# Using fread properly

Tags: c, wav, fread

The following function is not working i.e. it exits:

```
fread(buf, 1, 4, stdin);
buf[4] = '\0';

if (strcmp((char*)buf, "data")) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

I think if I can manually push fread farther down the stream it will eventually hit "data".

In other words how do I increment fread so that it skips bytes.

Examples of code always appreciated.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT 1**

Basically I'm parsing the header of a wav file on the iPhone. It is giving me some trouble and I believe it has to do with the way apple formats its audio files. Someone recommended to me running through the stream until I get "data" and then moving forward from there.

I hope this clarify things.

---

**EDIT 2**

[Here is documentation as to how the wav file header should look like](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/), but I'm wondering if the way apple formats theirs makes this inaccurate.

You will notice that 'data' is offset by 36 which is a multiple of four.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: @larmsmans, Please see my EDIT 1.

Comment: From your description of the problem, you need to do this in a loop and continue until fread returns 0, not fail on the first few bytes that are not "data".  The strncmp should be part of your while condition.  And keep in mind that data may not be exactly on a 4 byte offset from the start of the file.

Comment: So, do you want it to exit if buf contains "data" or do you want it to exit if buf does not contain "data" ? strcmp returns 0 (false) if the strings are equal

Comment: @Eric Brotto: why don't you use a library if you're parsing such a complicated, but ubiquitous file format?

Comment: @larsman Do you know of a library that runs on the iPhone which will parse the header and return an array of the samples?

Comment: @nos, from my understanding it exits if it returns an error. This code worked on a wav not created by an iPhone. Now I'm trying to run it on the iPhone and it is crashing at this point in code.

Comment: I'm not an iPhone dev, but you could try libsndfile: http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/

Comment: @larsman. That doesn't run on the iPhone. But thanks for your answer. I'm going to try to get this working asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in a stream like fashion and does what I think you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    long pos = 0;
    char buf;
    char str[5] = {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'};

    while ( fread(&buf, sizeof(char), 1, stdin) > 0 )
    {
        pos++;
        str[0] = str[1]; 
        str[1] = str[2];
        str[2] = str[3];

        str[3] = buf;
        str[4] = '\0';

        /* uncomment to see what got read ** printf("Read %s\n", str); */

        if ( strcmp(str, "data") == 0 )
        {
            break;
        }
    }


    printf("\"data\" occured after %ld bytes\n", pos);
    return 0;
}
```

This works by using a buffer I've called `str` and rotating the positions around in it. It will work until `data` appears.

Be aware it reads binary data, not text. So anything on stdin gets read, newlines included. However, if you adapt that to a file handle that shouldn't be a problem.

You can probably include this. The problem with using `fread` is that by design:

> The file position indicator for the stream (if defined) shall be advanced by the number of bytes successfully read.

Therefore if you advance by 4 bytes at a time, unless your data is exactly a multiple of 4 from the start of the data, you're going to miss it. For example:

```
123DATA
```

Fails if you read 4 bytes at a time.

Now, given this is a documented file format, are there not some header specs somewhere that tell you exactly how wide the fields are on the header? Or at least where they vary, such that you can read them off appropriately? Reading until `data` works, but isn't elegant, really.

Or, better still, I'm sure there must be a library for doing this somewhere.

---

**Edit** In response to the header of the wave file, since it is fixed and not that large, read the whole thing into a buffer.

```
uint8_t* hdr = malloc(36*sizeof(uint8_t));
fread(hdr, sizeof(uint8_t), 36);
```

Don't forget to free. At this point, you have the entire header extracted. I've used `uint8_t` to definitely be `8` bits. At this stage you can pull some interesting tricks, like casting that data to a struct. Just be aware of the endianness of the fields.

From then on, the stream is available to you in chunks, I believe. The first thing you need to do is this:

```
uint8_t chkid;
uint8_t chksz;
fread(&chkid, sizeof(uint8_t), 4, stream);
fread(&chksz, sizeof(uint8_t), 4, stream);
```

That'll grab you the data of that particular chunk. Assuming you're using a little endian system, You ought to be able to use `chksz` directly as an integer at this point, so now you can do:

```
uint8_t dataframe = malloc(chksz * sizeof(uint8_t));
```

Into which you can read the data:

```
fread(&dataframe, sizeof(uint8_t), chksz, stream);
```

This is of course assuming that the Apple wave format is the one described. Now, from that page:

> The WAVE file format is a subset of Microsoft's RIFF specification for the storage of multimedia files. A RIFF file starts out with a file header followed by a sequence of data chunks. A WAVE file is often just a RIFF file with a single "WAVE" chunk which consists of two sub-chunks -- a "fmt " chunk specifying the data format and a "data" chunk containing the actual sample data. Call this form the "Canonical form". Who knows how it really all works.

I've given you instructions that if used in a continual loop until there's nothing more on the stream, will allow you to read any number of data chunks a-la RIFF. You then need to process the data you get appropriately to break it down; i.e. split your data chunk that you read in up appropriately. If this is the only format you expect to read, you *could* just ignore additional chunks.

Now, the problem remains, *what is the apple format* and to be honest I've no idea!

Comment: Well I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, but I'm trying this approach. As for the documentation, please check EDIT 2 which I'm going to post right now.

Comment: This answer totally rocked! I took a bit of the code you posted and used it in my wav header parser. Couldn't believe how easily it worked. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's guaranteed that the first occurrence of `data` in ASCII is the start of the data header, since these four bytes might also occur as part of the [WAV format](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/)'s format chunk. A better way to parse a WAV would be (untested)

```
/* Returns the size of the data payload */
off_t skip_to_data_payload(FILE *fp)
{
    unsigned char buf[4];
    int i;
    off_t size;

    // the "data" magic should start at byte 36
    for (i=0; i<9; i++)
        fread(buf, 1, 4, fp);
    fread(buf, 1, 4, fp);
    if (memcmp(buf, "data", 4) != 0)
        return (off_t)(-1);

    // read size, assume little-endian
    fread(buf, 1, 4, fp);
    off_t size = buf[0] + (buf[1] << 8) + (buf[2] << 16) + (buf[4] << 24);

    return size;
}
```

Note: I've assumed PCM encoding and little endian files. Since Apple has used big endian processors in the past, you really should be checking for that. (Or **use a library**.)

Answer (score 0):

That strcmp will never work since you need an extra character for the string termination (\0) and you've already used up all 4 characters of your string.  Try `strncmp` instead.  And if you add more characters while working with stdin, don't forget about the line feeds.

Comment: @B Mitch, I will try what you say, but I did get this exact piece of coding running on my mac with a wav file that was not recorded on the iPhone. So I'm not %100 sure if your answer is relevant. But, hey I'm open to anything :)

Comment: @B Mitch, Also, when I  printf(" %s\n",(char*)buf); it reads FLLR which means it probably won't succeed, no?

Comment: You essentially have a buffer overflow, strcmp will read past the end of the data variable since there's no termination character.  The result will be very platform dependent on what data is after that data memory.  If it's a NULL, the code will work, but it's still error prone.

Comment: @B Mitch, I got the error: 'Too few arguments for strncmp. Any idea what I should change?

Comment: What did you enter on stdin that it read in FLLR?  printf expects a NULL just as strcmp, so you may be better off allocating a 5 byte buf, reading in 4 chars, and then setting byte 5 to \0.  You can also define the size of the string in printf with "%04s\n".

Comment: The definition is: int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);
So you should have strncmp((char*)buf, "data", 4)

Comment: The stdin is the URL of where the WAV file is. I'm going to try your last suggestion right now.

Comment: @B Mitch. Just to clarify, I do have a 5 byte buf with the fifth byte set to /0. i.e. buf[4] = /0. That is the fifth byte, no?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the code (too early in the morning), assuming buf is defined as char buf[5], or something equivalent, then yes, this should work.  No buf overflow.  See my comment to your original post.